# GitLab unable to automerge. Merge request contains merge conflicts that must be resolved

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

GitLab is unable to automerge requests. All merge requests get the message "This merge request contains merge conflicts that must be resolved. You can try it manually on the command line"

The message seems incorrect, and I tested this by creating a new branch with "git branch -b new-branch-name" and change a file that is not going to cause merge conflicts.

When I push this new branch and create a new merge request, Gitlab still says it cannot auto merge.

Any recommendations to fix this and what the reason is GitLab gives the "This merge request contains merge conflicts" message?

Comment: a quick google search shows https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3697 did you try their suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

This happens when your current branch is not in sync with remote branch. In this case, sometimes Git gets confused what to retain and what to ignore.

To fix this do following

```
; Go to master branch
git checkout develop

; update master branch
git pull

; go to you local branch and merge it with changes from master
git checkout local-branch
git merge develop
```

Resolve the conflicts if you get any. - [Reference](https://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts)

Your merge conflicts should be fixed by now.

Comment: Adding to the above answer to resolve conflicts - https://githowto.com/resolving_conflicts